# Ant build failed: srcdir does not exist

Tags: ant

I am very new to Apache Ant and I have the following problem when I run the ant command:
BUILD FAILED

```
C:\testANT\build.xml:17: srcdir "C:\testANT\src" does not exist!
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:925)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.ja
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAcces
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMet
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchU
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.jav
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(De
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
```

My build.xml file is:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="JarBuild" basedir="." default="jarfile">
<target name="init" description="Initializes properties">
    <property name="project.name" value="helloWorld"/>
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="etc.dir" value="etc"/>
</target>
<target name="prepare" description="Creates the build and classes directories" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>
<target name="compile" description="Compiles the code" depends="prepare">
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" />
</target>
<target name="jarfile" description="JARs the code" depends="compile">
<jar destfile="${build.dir}/${project.name}.jar"
basedir="${classes.dir}"
manifest="${etc.dir}/MANIFEST.MF" />
</target>
<target name="clean" description="delete the build directory" depends="init">
<delete dir="${build.dir}}" />
</target>
</project>
```

---

I mention that the build.xml file is in the main folder. 
Thanks a lot!
Regards!

Comment: What is the full path to the source code you want to compile?

Comment: is this correct?  `dir="${build.dir}}"`

Comment: And does the directory "C:\testANT\src" exist?